# Deleting set of rows using group_by in R

Tags: r, filter, group-by, tidyverse

In the 10 rows of data frame below, I have sightings of either whale or vessel and these sightings are grouped by ScanID.

By using the `dyplr` library, I am trying to figure out a way to remove the scan without any whales, in this case, it would scan 2 and 5.

I think `group_by` would be useful but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

```
whales <- data.frame(rubbing.beach = c('whale', 'vessel', 'vessel', 'vessel', 'whale', 'whale', 'whale', 'vessel', 'vessel', 'whale'), 
ScanID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6))
```

| X | Target | ScanID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | whale | 1 |
| 2 | vessel | 1 |
| 3 | vessel | 2 |
| 4 | vessel | 2 |
| 5 | whale | 3 |
| 6 | whale | 3 |
| 7 | whale | 4 |
| 8 | vessel | 4 |
| 9 | vessel | 5 |
| 10 | whale | 6 |

Leaving me with the output of:

| X | Target | ScanID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | whale | 1 |
| 2 | vessel | 1 |
| 3 | whale | 3 |
| 4 | whale | 3 |
| 5 | whale | 4 |
| 6 | vessel | 4 |
| 7 | whale | 6 |

Comment: Your sample doesn't have correct syntax - each instance of `"whale"` and `"vessel"` needs quotes, and your missing at least one `)`. I think my answer should work, but it is untested.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the syntax! unfortunately, it still doesn't work it is deleting the rows of vessels in scans 1 and 4 as well. But I want to keep those data points. Only delete the scans with just vessels.

Comment: If you provide working sample data I'll happily debug the answer. The easiest way to share data is with `dput()`, e.g. `dput(whales[1:10])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of `whales`, including all class and structure information.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I just realized my mistake. I was switching the position of whale and Target - "filter("whale" %in% Target)" in this code, I have them listed as different variables. Thank you so much for your swift reply! The code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this without `group_by` by extracting all the `ScanID` with `rubbing.beach == "whale"` and use it in `subset`.

```
subset(whales, ScanID %in% unique(ScanID[rubbing.beach == "whale"]))

#  rubbing.beach ScanID
#1         whale      1
#2        vessel      1
#3         whale      3
#4         whale      3
#5         whale      4
#6        vessel      4
#7         whale      6
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `filter` -

```
library(dplyr)

whales %>% filter(ScanID %in% unique(ScanID[rubbing.beach == "whale"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`group_by` is indeed necessary to consider each Scan ID, and `filter` is used to specify which rows to keep:

```
whales = read.table(text =
'X  Target  ScanID
1   whale   1
2   vessel  1
3   vessel  2
4   vessel  2
5   whale   3
6   whale   3
7   whale   4
8   vessel  4
9   vessel  5
10  whale   6', header = T)

library(dplyr)
whales %>%
  group_by(ScanID) %>%
  filter("whale" %in% Target)
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
# # Groups:   ScanID [4]
#       X Target ScanID
#   <int> <chr>   <int>
# 1     1 whale       1
# 2     2 vessel      1
# 3     5 whale       3
# 4     6 whale       3
# 5     7 whale       4
# 6     8 vessel      4
# 7    10 whale       6
```